# QObject::connect: No such signal eror C++

Tags: c++, qt, signals, slot

I'm stuck with an error and i have no idea where I am going wrong i tried running the signal with qapp aswell just to make sure it isn't the signal, and that was all fine. I have the SLOT declared as a public slot in my header file.

signal declaration:

```
void editPolygon(QVector <QPointF> points, QPolygonF &);
```

this is my connect:

```
  connect(this, SIGNAL(editPolygon(QVector <QPointF> &, QPolygonF &)), parent, SLOT(editPolygon(QVector <QPointF> points, CustomPolygon *poly)));
```

this is my slot thats emmiting the signal:

```
void CustomPolygon::editPolygons()
{
    QVector<QPointF> points;
    QPolygonF poly = mapToScene(polygon());

    emit editPolygon(points,poly);
}
```

and this is the void in mainwindow.cpp:

```
void MainWindow::editPolygon(QVector<QPointF> &points, CustomPolygon *poly)
{
}
```

thanks for you help in advance!

Comment: are you still using Qt4? if not use the modern syntax. Can you paste your signal declaration?

Comment: hi, ive pasted my declaration at the top, also yes I shall look into the new syntax now

Comment: Its not to be interpreted that "new" Qt's SIGNAL/SLOT syntax can work / while old doesn't .. the issue behind the error you get (`No such signal`) is because Signal/Slot _function signatures_ should exactly match

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *first* thing I would do is look very hard at the discrepancy in the second parameter of your signal/slot match.

One is `QPolygon&` and the other is `CustomPolygon*`. My understanding is that these had to match. Even if one were a proper subclass of the other, I don't think you can mix references and pointers like that.

---

And,regarding your (slightly paraphrased) comment:

> My slot has to stay as a pointer because it points to an item that is being deleted from a `QGraphicsScene`.
>
> My signal cant be a pointer because there is no conversion from a `QPolygonF` to a `QPolygonF *`, and I require `QPolygonF` to `mapToScene`.

I *think* I understand what you're saying, and there are a couple of issues.

If your slot takes a pointer that will be freed, you have to *give* it a pointer, and relinquish control of the object behind it (so either start with a dynamically allocated copy you're willing to let go of, or *make* a dynamically allocated copy from something you *don't* want to let go of).

And I'm not sure why you think there's no conversion from the object to a pointer to that object. I suppose that's *technically* true since the class *itself* doesn't provide a conversion, but this is really part of the *base* language:

```
Type thing;
Type *pointerToThing = &thing;
```

Both those issues should be solvable with something like:

```
QVector<QPointF> points;
QPolygonF thisIsMyPoly = mapToScene(polygon());
QploygonF *thisIsPolyForFreeing = new QPolygonF(thisIsMyPoly);
emit editPolygon(points, thisIsPolyForFreeing);
```

Your signal will still have to be changed to use a pointer rather than a reference and, hopefully, that will alleviate the mismatch.

---

If your pointer is an *actual* pointer to a `QPolygonF` that cannot be copied (because it's the pointer to the actual item being held in the `QGraphicsScene` and you therefore need the original pointer to remove it), I think you should just be able to pass that pointer as-is, assuming `mapToScene()` is returning a reference to it rather than a copy:

```
QPolygonF poly = mapToScene(polygon()); // get ref.
emit editPolygon(points, &poly);        // pass ref's address.
```

Comment: Hi, yes I know but the problem is I dont know a way of making it work any other way, my slot has to stay as a pointer because it points to an item that is being deleted from a QGraphicsScene and my signal cant be a pointe because there is no conversion from a QPolygonF to a QPolygonF *, and i require QPolygonF to mapToScene

Comment: @jaykay: I think I understand what you're saying, see the update.